# Can I use in LINQ to SQL a CROSS APPLY with checking of its SUM()?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a C# app. It uses EntityFramework.6.2.0 to access a DB in SQL Server 2012.
I need to execute in the app a following query using LINQ to SQL:
Tables used by the query:

```
CREATE TABLE [Work.Work] (
    [WorkCode] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
)
```

The 2nd table is a child of [Work.Work]; several its rows correspond to a [Work.Work] row:

```
CREATE TABLE [Work.WorkContributor] (
    [WorkContributorID]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [WorkCode]             INT            NOT NULL,
    [MechanicalShare]      DECIMAL (9, 4) NOT NULL,
)
```

The query (on T-SQL):

```
select * from [Work.Work] w
CROSS APPLY (select isnull(sum(wc.MechanicalShare), 0) as Sum from [Work.WorkContributor] wc
                where wc.WorkCode = w.WorkCode

    ) subQuery
where subQuery.Sum between 99.9 and 100.1
```

I need to create an analogue of this SQL query using LINQ to SQL.
I have managed to create an LINQ to SQL code with TWO  sub-queries  to  child [Work.WorkContributor] rows with calculation of SUM(wc.MechanicalShare). The result of the 1st sub-query I compare ‘>= 99.9’. The result of the 2nd sub-query I compare ‘<=100.1’.

Here it is:

```
var works = entityFrameworkContextObject.Work_Work.AsNoTracking();
works = from w in works
                        where ((99.9m < (from wc in w.Work_WorkContributor
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         toSum = wc.MechanicalShare
                                     }
                                ).Select(x => x.toSum).Sum()
                               )
                               &&
                               (100.1m > (from wc in w.Work_WorkContributor
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           toSum = wc.MechanicalShare
                                       }
                                ).Select(x => x.toSum).Sum()
                               )
                              )
select w;
```

Yes, it works – but a real SQL query to the DB has TWO separate sub-queries to [Work.WorkContributor].  It will work slow.

Here is the real SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[WorkCode] AS [WorkCode]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project1].[WorkCode] AS [WorkCode], 
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        (SELECT 
            SUM([Extent3].[MechanicalShare]) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Work.WorkContributor] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE [Project1].[WorkCode] = [Extent3].[WorkCode]) AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[WorkCode] AS [WorkCode], 
            (SELECT 
                SUM([Extent2].[MechanicalShare]) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Work.WorkContributor] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE [Extent1].[WorkCode] = [Extent2].[WorkCode]) AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Work.Work] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project2]
    WHERE (99.9 < [Project2].[C1]) AND (100.1 > [Project2].[C2])
```

Can I create a LINQ to SQL code with only one sub-query to [Work.WorkContributor]; and a real SQL query to the DB would have only one such sub-query?

Comment: What have you tried with LINQ so far? Could you provide your LINQ code?

Comment: I have posted the LINQ code and the SQL query generated by EF out of it into the original post.